# Bootstrap grid system: pull last column right regardless of other columns?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following simplified markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3" ng-if="isSuperUser()">
        Conditional column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        Column 3
    </div>
</div>
```

I want Column 3 to take up the last 6 grid columns always.  I also want the contents of Column 1 or Column 2 if not a super user to take up the first 3 grid columns depending.

The problem is when the Column 1 is not displayed, Column 2 and Column 3 shift to the left such that Column 3 is no longer on the right side.  A solution that seems hacky is to add a `<div class="col-lg-3" ng-if="!isSuperUser()">` before Column 3, but it seems like there may be a better solution.

I can't see anything in Bootstrap's documentation that demonstrates this functionality.  I see there is `push` and `pull` classes, but they don't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are asking for a way to prevent them from eventually taking up the full width of the page?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I updated the question. The problem is the columns shift to the left when Column 1 is not displayed, but I want Column 3 to be on the right at all times.

Comment: @im1dermike, why can't you add the ng-if condition inside the content instead of adding it on div. For e.g. `<div class="col-lg-3"><span  ng-if="isSuperUser()">Conditional column 1</span></div>`. Will that help?

Comment: @CuriousMind: Because that wouldn't pull Column 2 to the left if Column 1 isn't displayed.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I misunderstood the requirement. Well in that case, you will have to use approach you have suggested in your question itself (use another div with exclamation operator). [Also I upvoted your question, I don't know why someone has downvoted, the question looks genuine to me.]

Comment: @CuriousMind: I think the guy who gave a JS answer and got mad that I didn't like it did. :\

Comment: To be clear the original requirements don't say anything about not using JS. If I ever do downvote an answer, it has serious issues or completely misses the requirements set forth by the OP. Even then I comment before a downvote so the answer can be improved/rectified. I don't downvote based on personal style. Upvotes usually receive a comment or an upvoted comment if it already exists. Anyways that's how I do it. In the end they're your points, spend them how you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/netuwibocu/1/edit?html,css,output)

you can try nest **row** into the **.col-xs-***. That's mean you could use the out **row** to fixed position before you want hidden something.

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">col 6
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
          10
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">col 6
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          your purpose
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to [offset columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) in Bootstrap. *Conditionally add* the class `.col-lg-offset-3` to the second column.

Comment: That will always offset the column.

Comment: Only add it to the column when column 1 is not present. What's hard about that?

Comment: What's hard about it?  Nothing.  I don't want to add javascript.  The hacky solution I posted in my question is better than this.

Comment: Can you not added/remove the class on the backend? Looks like you're using Angular, which is JavaScript if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Of course.  But then I need to add javascript to supply `ng-class` to the one column.  Just doesn't seem like the solution go beyond HTML...

Comment: Then I think your solution is going to be to added an extra div as I'm assuming you're going to use `display: none;`.

Comment: I would never use inline styles.

Comment: LOL, OMG. I didn't say inline styles. You could very easily use `display: none;` in some version of `.example { display: none; }`. Still don't understand why you're against JS when using Angular.

Comment: I see.  I like keeping my Angular controllers as lean as possible and, to me, this should be solved via HTML.  I'd rather go w/ the solution I offered in my question than add a function to my Angular controller to get `ng-class`.

Comment: Your requirement has a conditional in it, either display or not display. So something somewhere needs to be aware of the context and we both know that CSS cannot do that. If you don't want to add a couple lines of code and simply use what's already available to you then I think the additional DIV solution with ng-if that you have suggested is the way to go.